# Suppress email address in Google sign in Branding information

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

We have set up Google+ based login (OAuth2) to our website to allow people to login with their existing Google accounts .

The login piece all works fine but the email address that gets displayed for the "Branding Information" is my personal email address (i.e. me@example.com). I would like this email id to be suppressed not shown.

I can edit the title and logo but there is no option to change the email address. How can I change the email to not show?

The below site does it and I can't find any information on that ....

https://dashboard.janrain.com/signin#

Comment: I don't see your email address anywhere in the authentication process. Are you sure you're not confusing the email address google shows when you're logged in? Or did you fix it? Or can you specify where the email address is shown? Do you still see it if you're using an incongnito/private browsing window?

Comment: @OrganicLawnDIY - the email address appears on the consent screen. Next to Product name, there is a small down arrow , when you click on that there is 'Developer info' , next to that there is email address of the developer account holder of that api. We do not want to show that email address like the site https://dashboard.janrain.com/signin# does. This is the example I am showing.

Comment: My mistake. I confused that site as being your site.

Comment: The account you're using, is it for a person? Is there any way to have the account be a Google+ page? I wonder if that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to suppress an email address from being shown, however it is possible to change the email address that is displayed.  See answer to [Suppress email address in Google sign in Branding information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620474/suppress-email-address-in-google-sign-in-branding-information).

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google OAuth 2.0, in this you need to create app and you get access on various api's of Google. So Google show your email address.

But Janrain is using open id, in open id doesn't require to create app. but through Openid you can't get access on Google api's you just get authentication data only.

You can also noticed that Google showing on accept page your app name but for janrain it is showing host login.janrain.com.

So in OAuth Google have information about consumer but in open id Google doesn't have any information about consumer except callback URL.